# I'm trying to install kali linux on a new laptop that currently has windows on it, but my C:\ won't appear when picking a partition to install on

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I tried a new version of Kali on a new flash drive, I tried checking the bios, I tried to look at the drive, but realized I can't format my C:\ for obvious reasons, and I tried searching youtube for answers. Also I tried doing it manually, but even there wasn't anything to help me. Here is the text that pops up:

```
Partition disks

This an overview of your currently configured partitions and mount points. Select a partition to modify its settings (file system, mount point, etc.), a free space to create partitions, or a device to initialize partition table. 

Guided partitioning 
Configure iSCSI volumes 

SCSI2 (0, 0, 0) (sda) - 63.5 GB SanDisk Cruzer Dial

Undo changes to partitions 
Finish partitioning and write changes to disk
```

The SanDisk above is obviously my USB and I am not willing to plug my USB in every time I want to use Kali since the goal of this is to have it permanently installed on the computer. reacp: New Laptop, secure boot off, C:\ drive not showing up.

Comment: One possibility is the SATA controller mode is not AHCI but RAID/RST. (It could even affect NVMe drive because the Intel remap crap is/was not supported by the kernel.)

Comment: I am working in Kali here ..  Easier (in spades) to build a Kali Virtual Machine and learn ho to use it.